# American spellings

Tags: discussion

I've had a few posts "corrected" for spelling where the European, or sometimes world excluding US spelling has been changed to the American spelling.

For example, someone changed "metres" (the correct name, and used by most of the world) to meters.

It's not really a big thing but it does grate that a) some people seem not to recognise that this is an international site and b) they assume that my spelling is flawed.

Thoughts?  Or should I just get my coat?

Comment: I don't agree that "metres" is the "correct" name and used by "most" of the world. Both "metres" and "meters" are correct, depending on perspective.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us Generally you can rollback or reject edits that **do not improve the post**, and changing the localization of the post is an example of that.

Comment: seriously, 'correct spelling'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been brought up many times on SE sites. I would basically say what Dan commented. Read this post: [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)

Tags are always US-English, but in the title or body of posts, US or UK is fine. If someone edits the post, you can roll it back stating that the spelling is correct, but simply UK. If you end up in an edit war with someone over spelling, link them to this post, and flag it for moderator attention if necessary.

Comment: I have modified a few UKism by mistake. once I changed centring to centering, because I thought it was missing an 'e'.  But i've gotten used to the UK spellings, and just leave them be.